# Search for empty cells; copy adjacent cell to message box; delete row or add text to empty cell

Tags: vba

Loop through a range of column D for empty cells. Once an empty cell is found, copy text from adjacent cell in column C to Message Box. The message box gives the option to delete the row or add text to the empty cell. Repeat until no empty cells of column D exist.

The expectation is to remove rows that contains useless information and keep the rows that does. The rows that does have useful info will be newly categorized.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRowCat As Integer
Dim cat As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

lastRowCat = ws.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row   'This gives the last Row with a nonempty cell in column A
For i = 2 To lastRowCat
    If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 4)) Then
    abc = MsgBox(ws.Cells(i, 3), vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Save Transaction")

    If abc = vbYes Then
    cat = Application.InputBox("Add New Category" + " " + ws.Cells(i, 3))
    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = cat

    Else
    ws.Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Delete

    End If

    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRowCat = 300
    blnks = 300
    For i = 2 To lastRowCat
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 4)) Then
            blnks = Range("D2" & ":" & "D" & lastRowCat).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
            abc = MsgBox(ws.Cells(i, 3) & " " & "$" & ws.Cells(i, 5), vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, "Save Transaction ?" & " " & blnks & " " & "left")

            If abc = vbYes Then
                cat = Application.InputBox("Add New Category" & " " & ws.Cells(i, 3))
                ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "(new)" & cat
                lastRowCat = ws.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
            Else
                ws.Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Delete
                lastRowCat = ws.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
            End If

        End If

        If i >= lastRowCat Then
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i
```

Comment: This version kills the For Loop when the iteration i is greater or equal to the count of blank rows.